# Reverse cumprod in R

Tags: r

How do you reverse `cumprod` in R?

```
x <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1)
a <- cumprod(1 - x)
```

Now, I would like to get `x` from `a` again.

Comment: You can also use `diff` on the logarithmic scale: `1 - c(a[1], exp(diff(log(a))))`

Comment: @Roland  Have you tested the accuracy of the result vs. the accuracy of, say, tonytonov's  answer?  In particular, for "ugly" `x` sequences with very large or very small numbers (next to each other, etc)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Of course I have not. If you have something like that you are most likely in trouble anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1 - c(a[1], a[-1] / a[-length(a)])
[1] 0.5 0.3 0.1
```